# Do you like your major? How to express the feeling that I don't hate it andI don't like it either

Tags: word-choice

I don't like my major, at the same time, I don't hate it either. I never skip classes and I do my homework. But I don't have a passion for it, I don't particularly like it.

So, how do I respond to the question "Do you like your major?"

Is "I'm neutral to it." an ok answer?

Thanks!

Comment: Answer it with "*How to express the feeling that I don't hate it and I don't like it either?*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm indifferent towards my major.

Indifferent: Regarded as neither good nor bad. M-W